# Excel reference to same address of other cell

Tags: excel, reference

I have an excel sheet containing product and price information. In another sheet I try to make a list of products that combine into another product. What I want to achieve is that I can use one cell to reference to the product name and another to get the price of this product.

I know it is possible to get the value of a cell in reference to another using functions like index and address, so that is not the problem. I cannot figure out how to get the address where the product cell is pointing at.

Example:

```
+---+-------+--------------+------------+
|   |   A   |      B       |     C      |
+---+-------+--------------+------------+
| 1 | name  |  price       | quantity   |
+-------+--------------+------------+
| 2 | test  | 12           | 1          |
+---+-------+--------------+------------+
| 3 |       |              |            |
+---+-------+--------------+------------+
| 4 | =$A$2 |  Price of B2 |------------|
+---+-------+--------------+------------+
```

At Cell B4 I want the value of column B of the row referenced by A4. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A4,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

[image]